# How does the following code work without the proper action attribute being set?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a code, in a file called `service.php` which does as follows:

```
if ((!empty($_POST)) && ($_POST['action'] == 'addRunner'))
{
    // Code to add entry into database
}

function fail($message) 
{
    die(json_encode(array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => $message)));
}
function success($message) 
{
    die(json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $message)));
}
```

And the file to send the data via POST method using AJAX is:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function() 
{
    var data = $("#addRunner :input").serialize();

    $.post($("#addRunner").attr('action'), data, function(json)
    {
        if(json.status == 'fail')
            alert(json.message);

        if(json.status == 'success')
        {
            alert(json.message);
            clearInputs();
        }
    },"json");
});
```

The action attribute of the form `#addRunner` is:

```
<form action="service.php" id="addRunner" name="addRunner" method="POST">
    <!-- Form Elements -->
</form>
```

**Note that the action attribute for the form element** is simply `service.php` instead of `service.php?action=addRunner`. However, the form still works perfectly, and successfully adds new "runner" information into the database. How does this happen?

Shouldn't the condition `($_POST['action'] == 'addRunner')` fail and prevent the code to enter data into the database from running?

---

**For the sake of completeness, the entirity of my code is as below.**

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>2011 Race Finishers</title> 
        <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <header>
            <h2>2011 Race Finishers!</h2>
        </header>
        <div id="main">
            <ul class="idTabs"> 
                <li><a href="#male">Male Finishers</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#female">Female Finishers</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#all">All Finishers</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#new">Add New Finishers</a></li>
            </ul> 
            <div id="male">
                <h4>Male Finishers</h4>
                <ul id="finishers_m"></ul>
            </div> 
            <div id="female">
                <h4>Female Finishers</h4>
                <ul id="finishers_f"></ul>      
            </div>
            <div id="all">
                <h4>All Finishers</h4>
                <ul id="finishers_all"></ul>
            </div>
            <div id="new">
                <h4>Add New Finishers</h4>
                <form action="service.php" id="addRunner" name="addRunner" method="POST">
                    First Name: <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" id="txtFirstName"> <br>
                    Last Name: <input type="text" name="txtLastName" id="txtLastName"> <br>
                    Gender: <select name="ddlGender" id="ddlGender">
                        <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                        <option value="m">Male</option>
                        <option value="f">Female</option>
                    </select> <br>
                    Finish Time: 
                    <input type="text" id="txtMinutes" name="txtMinutes" size="10" maxlength="2">
                    <input type="text" id="txtSeconds" name="txtSeconds" size="10" maxlength="2">
                    <br><br>
                    <button id="btnSave" type="sumbit" name="btnSave">Add Runner</button>
                    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="addRunner">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <h4>Congratulations to all our finishers!</h4>
            <button id="btnStart">Start Page Updates</button>
            <button id="btnStop">Stop Page Updates</button>
            <br>
            <span id="freq"></span><br><br>     
            Last Updated: <div id="updatedTime"></div>
        </footer>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var FREQ = 10000 ;
    var repeat = true;

    function showFrequency(){
        $("#freq").html( "Page refreshes every " + FREQ/1000 + " second(s).");
    }

    function startAJAXcalls(){

        if(repeat){
            setTimeout( function() {
                    getDBRacers();
                    startAJAXcalls();
                },  
                FREQ
            );
        }
    }

    function getXMLRacers(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "finishers.xml",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success:  function(xml){

                $('#finishers_m').empty();
                $('#finishers_f').empty();
                $('#finishers_all').empty();

                $(xml).find("runner").each(function() {
                    var info = '<li>Name: ' + $(this).find("fname").text() + ' ' + $(this).find("lname").text() + '. Time: ' + $(this).find("time").text() + '</li>';
                    if( $(this).find("gender").text() == "m" ){
                        $('#finishers_m').append( info );
                    }else if ( $(this).find("gender").text() == "f" ){
                        $('#finishers_f').append( info );
                    }else{  }
                    $('#finishers_all').append( info );
                });

                getTimeAjax();
            }
        });
    }

    function getDBRacers()
    {
        $.getJSON("service.php?action=getRunners", function(json)
        {
            if(json.runners.length > 0)
            {
                $('#finishers_m').empty();
                $('#finishers_f').empty();
                $('#finishers_all').empty();

                $.each(json.runners, function() 
                {
                    var info = '<li>Name: ' + this['fname'] + ' ' + this['lname'] + '. Time: ' + this['time'] + '</li>';
                    if(this['gender'] == 'm')
                    {
                        $('#finishers_m').append(info);
                    }
                    else if(this['gender'] == 'f')
                    {
                        $('#finishers_f').append(info);
                    }
                    else {}

                    $('#finishers_all').append(info);
                });
            }
        });
        getTimeAjax();
    }

    function getTimeAjax(){
        var time = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: "time.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $('#updatedTime').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $("#btnStop").click(function(){
        repeat = false;
        $("#freq").html( "Updates paused." );
    });

    $("#btnStart").click(function(){
        repeat = true;
        startAJAXcalls();
        showFrequency();
    }); 

    showFrequency();
    getDBRacers();
    startAJAXcalls();

    $("#btnSave").click(function() 
    {
        var data = $("#addRunner :input").serialize();

        $.post($("#addRunner").attr('action'), data, function(json)
        {
            if(json.status == 'fail')
                alert(json.message);

            if(json.status == 'success')
            {
                alert(json.message);
                clearInputs();
            }
        },"json");
    });

    function clearInputs()
    {
        $("#addRunner:input").each(function(){
            $(this).val('');
        });
    }

    $("#addRunner").submit(function() {
        return false;
    });

});
```

And finally the contents of Service.php is:

```
<?php

    if ((!empty($_POST)) && ($_POST['action'] == 'addRunner'))
    {
        $fname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtFirstName']);
        $lname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtLastName']);
        $gender = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ddlGender']);
        $minutes = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtMinutes']);
        $seconds = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtSeconds']);

        if(preg_match('/[^\w\s]/i', $fname) || preg_match('/[^\w\s]/i', $lname)) 
        {
            fail('Invalid name provided.');
        }
        if( empty($fname) || empty($lname) ) 
        {
            fail('Please enter a first and last name.');
        }
        if( empty($gender) ) 
        {
            fail('Please select a gender.');
        }
        if( empty($minutes) || empty($seconds) ) {
            fail('Please enter minutes and seconds.');
        }

        $time = $minutes.":".$seconds;
        $query = "INSERT INTO runners SET first_name='$fname', last_name='$lname', gender='$gender', finish_time='$time'";
        $result = db_connection($query);

        if ($result) 
        {
            $msg = "Runner: ".$fname." ".$lname." added successfully" ;
            success($msg);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            fail('Insert failed.');
        } 
        exit;
    }
    else if($_GET['action'] == 'getRunners')
    {

        $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, gender, finish_time FROM runners ORDER BY finish_time ASC";
        $result = db_connection($query);

        $runners = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            array_push($runners, array('fname' => $row['first_name'], 'lname' => $row['last_name'], 'gender' => $row['gender'], 'time' => $row['finish_time']));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("runners" => $runners));
        exit;
    }

    function db_connection($query)
    {
        $dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','runner_db_user','runner_db_password','race_info')
            or die('Error connecting to Database');

        return mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    }

    function fail($message) 
    {
        die(json_encode(array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => $message)));
    }
    function success($message) 
    {
        die(json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $message)));
    }

?>
```

Comment: you know the difference between: GET and POST?

Comment: @LuciaAngermüller Yes, but that doesn't explain how the action attribute of `#addRunner` is changed from `service.php` to `service.php?action=addRunners`. Care to explain, please?

Comment: It happens because of your jquery script. I don't want to give everything, but you send the data via POST to an GET Adress. you should look up jquery serialize, post etc.

Comment: @LuciaAngermüller Care to elaborate how exactly this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work reason behind this is `action` is value of `name` attribute from hidden field.  It is not the action of your `form` tag. If you want to make it fail for testing purpose you should change the value of hidden field to something else in your `form` and then check again.

This is your hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="addRunner">
```

You can do like this for testing only

```
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="addRunners">
```

It will not satisfy this `if` condition

```
if ((!empty($_POST)) && ($_POST['action'] == 'addRunner'))
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `$("#addRunner").attr('action')` presents the value of `service.php`, does it not? How is the hidden field relevant? Where is its value accessed?

Comment: `var data = $("#addRunner :input").serialize();` you are passing this data to ajax. You're right that above jquery is presents the value of `service.php`. So when you use serialize it will take all the input fields and dropdowns from your `form`. That's why the hidden field value is passing through your ajax.

Comment: so, basically, when we write `$_POST['action']`, it refers to the value of the hidden field called `action` and _NOT_ the action attribute of the form element, right?

Comment: exactly. This is in your case :)